# In-line tables with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having a major problem trying to create in-line tables with divs instead of tables and CSS. My issue is that I have 3 types of rows that aren't really in sync, so expectedly, do not line up. I am wondering if there is a solution or a better approach.

As you'll see in the fiddle, I am trying to get the header, row, and child row to line up. All columns and headers have the same width %, but their overall widths will be different. Also, the child row should be indented to appear under the parent.

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ptag0b/15/

## HTML

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<div id = "headers">
    <div class = "col header_name">Name</div>
    <div class = "col header_id">ID</div>
    <div class = "col header_country">Country</div>
</div>

<div id = "table">
    <div class = "row" data-id = "1">
        <div class = "col button">+</div>
        <div class = "col name">Bob Dolle</div>
        <div class = "col id">1234</div>
        <div class = "col country">America</div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row_child" data-parent = "1">
        <div class = "col name">Joe Dolle</div>
        <div class = "col id">67788</div>
        <div class = "col country">America</div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#headers{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.row{
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.row_child{
    background-color:#AAA8A8;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.col{
    display:inline-block;
}
#table{
    padding:5px;
}
.header_name, .name{
    width:30%
}
.header_id, .id{
    width:10%;
}
.header_country, .country{
    width:25%;
}
.button{
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: If you're displaying tabular information, what's the problem with using tables?

Comment: For tabular data use `<table>`...

Comment: I didn't think they would work well with in-line elements. Like adding a child row with the same columns. How will I indent the child row and maintain the proportions?

Comment: ... are you looking for this (generating cells where missing) http://jsfiddle.net/b6ptag0b/32/ of course nothing is alike a table when accurate and needed . without style, no way to properly understand the meaning of div contents, just words, numbers aside eachothers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, despite the "use tables" argument (I can see why you want to use DIVS), what you want to do is incredibly easy with CSS, but you're using a really convoluted logic. You can use a columns approach instead of rows, or using your rows approach, just give each columns the same width and include the `.button` class in the same div as the name , then simply add some table logic to your `divs`

```
#table, #headers {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.col {
    display:table-cell;
    width:30%;
}
#headers {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.row {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.row_child {
    background-color:#AAA8A8;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.header_id, .id {
    width:10%;
}
.header_country, .country {
    width:25%;
}
.button {
    padding:0 10px;
    float:left;
}
.row_child .name {
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/deuek1k4/)

Comment: without style, content is a mess of words and numbers, that is why table is usefull ... it tells in wich col and ro each stands and so,  to what it is related. ... else another approach for a table like formated tag soup :) http://jsfiddle.net/b6ptag0b/32/

Comment: I'm not arguing on the use (or not) of tables, just giving the OP an answer based on his approach. However, that's exactly why HTML and CSS goes together nowadays. I know hardcore programmers tend to use tables for everything, but coming from a UI/UX design background, I tend to concentrate on visuals, and there's absolutely no way a table will ever be superior to divs in terms of usability and styling (as you kind of mention). You can do things with divs that are simply impossible with tables, and in this case I kinda understand why the OP is using divs, that + sign is the clue

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will allow you to use new CSS Table Layouts, for example:

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ptag0b/30/

## HTML

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "headers">
        <div class = "col header_name">Name</div>
        <div class = "col header_id">ID</div>
        <div class = "col header_country">Country</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row" data-id = "1">
        <div class = "col name">Bob Dolle</div>
        <div class = "col id">1234</div>
        <div class = "col country">America</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row_child" data-parent = "1">
        <div class = "col name">Joe Dolle</div>
        <div class = "col id">67788</div>
        <div class = "col country">America</div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#wrapper{
    display: table;
}

#headers{
    background-color:#ccc;
    display: table-row;
}

.row{
    background-color:#ddd;
    display: table-row;
}

.row_child{
    background-color:#AAA8A8;
    display: table-row;
}

.col{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
}
```